# A funny looking cipher puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, cipher, steganography

What secrets does this jester hold? Hints are found down the road.

[image: jester-ovlaL8t.gif]

*A hint, or rather, that what is held transcribed:*

> https://imgur.com/a/ovlaL8t

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site! Did you create this puzzle?

Comment: Yes, I did. :) So if you need to know anything eventually I'll be here!

Comment: As a sidenote, feel free to post (spoilered) partial solutions for others to build upon. This is not a cipher stack, but deduction work may require multiple steps. Saves others some of the work work.

Comment: @MarkMarketing does this involve hex color codes?

Comment: @1357924680a (rot13) Gur fcrpvsvp urk inyhrf nera'g vzcbegnag, whfg gung gurl ner qvssrerag vf rabhtu.

Comment: Mark Marketing said "The specific hex values aren't important, just that they are different is enough."

Comment: @Ronchen Luo Correct, but for your information the rot13 was just to not spoil things for those that care about that. :) You can't use spoilers in comments, hence why the rot13.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with converting this to an indexed image, and then figuring out some kind of pattern>

Comment: @newQOpenWid Determining how information is stored in the image can be done at a glance. However, the information does need to be "transcribed" to a form in which it then must be processed. Your approach could work for this, though you may want to choose what index to attribute to what colour yourself. Of the multiple options, one gives a more coherent range.

Comment: [Text transcription](https://pastebin.com/0rJrdG5P)